# How to re-project graphics returned from a geoprocessing service on the fly?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, coordinate-system, geoprocessing-service

I have a geoprocessing service returning a feature-set in WGS_84. I want to show that graphics on the map using Arcgis JS api.
As I can see my geometries are not re-projected on the fly, since my base-map is in a projected coordinate system and my geometries keep their geographic coordinate system (wgs_84). How can I tell the graphic layer to be re-projected in the fly so as to follow my base-map's spatial reference ? 
In other words I want to find a way to reproject a graphics layer in a desired projected system, from inside the arcgis JS api using javascript, and after I have received my results (graphics )from the GP service.

Comment: @PolyGeo, Thanks fro your notice. However, No it is not duplicate. Here I am clearly asking how to reproject a graphics layer on the fly, from within the JS api, while in the other post , how I could make the GP service to return already projection-converted graphics. It is different.

Comment: I think it would be worth editing both questions to make that distinction clearer.  I may or may not be the only one that reads them several times and concludes that they seem to be very similar if not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing your basemap is in Web Mercator?

Handle the graphics and convert their geometry to Web Mercator individually

```
arrayUtil.forEach(graphicsLayer.graphics, function(g){
  var geom = esri.geometry.geographicToWebMercator(g.geom);
  g.setGeometry(geom);
});
```